# Why are baseball statistics called "sabermetrics"?

Tags: etymology

Loosely defined, sabermetrics is the study/usage/development of baseball statistics. I get the "metrics" part of the word, and I know what a saber is. But, what do sabers have to do with baseball?

My only idea is that the baseball bat is kind of like a saber, but that seems to be a stretch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems to be an acronym, like SCUBA:

> S(ociety for) A(merican) B(aseball) R(esearch) + -metrics.

Source: [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sabermetrics?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic)

Comment: You'd think they'd be nice to me and type it SABeRmetrics. :-)

Comment: I used to see it often as SABRmetrics.